# Integration question: how to solve the integration of the Quasi-binomial distribution

Tags: integration

The quasi-binomial score $U$ for one sample is defined as $$Q(\mu,y)= \int_{y}^{\mu} \frac{y-t}{t(1-t)} dt,\ y\in\{0,1\}.$$
How to solve this? The answer given in my note is $y\log\mu+\log(1-\mu).$ This could be incorrect. What is the correct answer?

What I have done is, $$Q(\mu,y)= \int_{y}^{\mu} \frac{y-t}{t(1-t)} dt = y\log(\frac{t}{1-t})|_y^{\mu}+\log(1-t)|_y^\mu.$$ Then I got stuck.

Comment: You have dx, but x does not appear in the integrand.  However, assuming x means t, your result (which looks right) is different from the answer which looks wrong, except for y=1.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Thank you. I've updated my question.

Comment: You used dx in two expressions, but fixed only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$I=\int_{y}^{\mu}\frac{y-t}{t(1-t)}dt=\int_{y}^{\mu} \left(\frac{y-1}{1-t}+\frac{y}{t}\right) dt= [(1-y)\ln (1-t)+ y \ln t]_{y}^{\mu}=(1-y)\ln\frac{1-\mu}{1-y}+y\ln \frac{\mu}{y}. $$

Comment: Can $y=0$ for last equation?

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in the final expression now I have corrected it. If  it helps you, you may put $y=1$, then answer will be $ \ln \mu$. But $y=0$ will give divergence.